# Minus equal operator doesnt call property setter python

Tags: python, python-3.x, getter-setter

I have my code setup this way:

```py
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.offset = [0,0]

    @property
    def offset(self):
        return self._offset

    @offset.setter
    def offset(self,offset):
        print("set")
        self._offset = offset

test = Test()
test.offset[1] -= 1
```

but the setter is being called only once even though I am changing my variable twice, anyone is able to help ?

Comment: The last line of your code is calling the getter not the setter. You _get_ the list from the test object and then you alter its contents.

Comment: Oooh , so I modify the reference of the object right? @khelwood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test.offset[1] -= 1
```

This line of your code is calling the getter not the setter. You *get* the list from the test object and then you alter its contents.

Same as if you wrote:

```
v = test.offset   # get the list
v[1] -= 1         # alter the contents of the list
```